How to verify blob create triggered Azure function received the event
I am trying to troubleshot a blob create triggered Azure function which failing without any log application insight, however even it run it often have a big gap in time between event sent from storage account and the actually function run, and more important sometimes it is not running at all.
I can see there are a Function Execution Count under Overview > Metrics however I am more interested to the detailed events, wonder if I can get access to the event logs which Function Execution Count used to calculate the number?


How to verify blob create triggered Azure function received the event

You can simply use traces in logs section of Function app to get to know the clear logs of all functions in Function app:

To get these logs you need to enable application insights.
Or you can use Diagnostic settings and send logs to Log analytics workspace:

All logs in detailed are sent to Log analytics workspace, You can use KQL query FunctionAppLogs to know how many times function is executed and all.

Thanks, unfortunately as mention in the question application insights is not working in our environment, so we need some other method to verify.

Then only way you can check is, send a message to a queue using code inside the function, so whenever event occurs there is a message, I fell nothing more can be done without app insights

As you're unable to use application insights, you can navigate to "Diagnose and Solve problem" blade inside your function app to check function execution and error filtering right time frame. Hope this helps.
